# Referencing other researcher's observation as lead-in phrase in scientific writing

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice, style

I'm currently discussing a turn of phrase with a colleague. Both of us are non-native speakers.

The context is "referencing prior work by other researchers within a scientific paper".

The three discussed possibilities are:

1. As has been observed by Bohnenschneider et al., shlurg gnebs the Tseptsn.
2. As it has been observed by Bohnenschneider et al., shlurg gnebs the Tseptsn.
3. As observed by Bohnenschneider et al., shlurg gnebs the Tseptsn.

Is any of these variants wrong, and, if not, is there one variant that is preferable for stylistic reasons? (Or might they have a different meaning?)

Comment: What are the last four words? They seem to be nonsense, but you include "the". If you don't want to include your actual text, you can just use an ellipsis (". . ."). Also, [please tell us which option you think is best and why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please). Doing so will greatly help you to get more useful answers.

Comment: Those are all wrong because they're formatted as sentences --with a capital letter at the beginning and a period at the end-- but none have a subject or main verb. Please show us how you actually intend to use this reference in the context, and replace the nonsense words.

Comment: @gotube I assumed *shlurg* was the subject and *gnebs* was the verb.  I just [glarked](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glark) it from context, you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#3 is the clear winner for me. #1 would do, but the "has been" adds nothing and makes it slightly more clumsy.

THE "it" in #2 strikes me as possibly ungrammatical, but I'm not sure why. And even if it's fine, the whole thing, like #1, loses to #3 because of unnecessary wordiness.

The whole thing does concern me though. Today, shlurg may simply be gnebing the Tseptsn, but before we know it the Stkompsin may be getting gnebed as well. And ftang'ed if I'm not mistaken. Before long we'll have to deal with Ole Biscuitbarrel, and then where will we be!